# Is it necessary that the path of an object in uniform motion is a straight path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, relative-motion, inertia

What does the path of an object look like when it is in uniform motion?

Comment: Please would you explain what you think the answer is? What does "uniform motion" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on the context and is rather a question about nomenclature than physics.

Usually, in elementary kinematics "uniform motion" is defined as motion along a straight path. Uniform motion here means an unchanged state of motion, that is a motion where the velocity remains constant. If the velocity remains the same $\vec v(t) = \vec v_0$, then the path will obviously be the straight line $\vec r(t) = \vec r_0 + t \vec v_0$.

The term uniform circular movement is common when discussion the elementary kinematics of rotation, then the path will obviously be a circle.

In more general terms, if you consider motion of an object constrained to a submanifold of space (that means some surface or some arbitrary path), then it would be natural to consider movement along geodesics as uniform motion. This notion coincides with the notion of uniform circular motion given above, if we constrain the object to move on a circle. It also coincides with the notion of a constant velocity: Geodesics are exactly those paths along which the velocity is covariantly constant.

Comment: Do you mean that the answer is yes,the path for a body in uniform motion is a straight path?